# GeoJSON from GIS Steiermark not convertible to Feature in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, geojson, epsg

I want to convert a GeoJSON (downloaded from GIS Steiermark) to a feature in ArcMap (the JSON I want to import is a polygon of the Riegersburg in Austria). This does not work. After checking the JSON and editing it to fit the ArcGIS standard, I think the problem might be the EPSG code. My projection is WGS 84 Decimal Degrees, but I don't know the EPSG Code nor the exact projection name.

Can you point me in the right direction (or to the right EPSG Code)?

This is the text of the edited JSON file so far:

````
"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG: ???"}},
"features":[{"type":"Feature","id":0,"geometry":{"type":"Polygon",
                "coordinates":[[[15.931564324198687,47.00273464881419],...]]
            },"properties":{"FID":0,"Id":0}}]}```
````

Comment: WGS84 coordinates in longitude-latitude order is the default in GeoJSON so it seems that you could just remove the whole crs. There is no ArcGIS standard for GeoJSON, there is only the GeoJSON standard and if your data are compliant then ArcGIS should read it or it has a bug. Can you provide test data?

Comment: {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              15.931391676304079,
              47.002813604576865
            ],
            [
              15.931909897756166,
              47.002592797004304
            ],

Comment: [
              15.930417145900808,
              47.003013150569885
            ],
            [
              15.931021082728128,
              47.00291779695354
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "_meta.tool": "polygon",
        "_meta.text": "Sketch Polygon"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I took some coordinates out in the middle but otherwise this is the original file that I downloaded from GIS Steiermark. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems that ArcMap cannot import GeoJSON because the JSON to features tool in ArcMap 10.8 supports only ESRI JSON. From the tool help:

> Converts JSON features based on ArcGIS REST API specification into a
> feature class. The feature class will have fields, geometry type, and
> spatial reference as defined in the JSON.

The JSON To Features tool in ArcGIS Pro supports also GeoJSON. I edited the data that I captured from your comments slightly so that it mostly validates at https://geojsonlint.com. I had to copy the first coordinates to last coordinates to make the ring to close. The right hand rule does not seem to be so critical.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [15.931391676304079, 47.002813604576865],
                    [15.931909897756166, 47.002592797004304],
                    [15.930417145900808, 47.003013150569885],
                    [15.931391676304079, 47.002813604576865]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "_meta.tool": "polygon",
            "_meta.text": "Sketch Polygon"
        }
    }]
}
```

Then I imported the data with the JSON To Features geoprocessing tool and here is the result:

[image]

If you can't use ArcGIS Pro I suggest to convert the GeoJSON into for example shapefile format with QGIS or GDAL.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Data Interoperability license, you may want to look into the [ArcMap's Data Interoperability extension](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/data-interoperability/what-is-the-data-interoperability-extension-.htm).

The GeoJSON file format is listed in the [supported formats](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/data-interoperability/supported-formats-with-the-data-interoperability-extension.htm).

However, I cannot verify if that would work as I neither have ArcGIS Desktop nor the license.

---

There is a blog post [here](https://opengislab.com/blog/2018/11/8/adding-and-viewing-geojson-in-qgis-and-arcgis) writing about importing a GeoJSON into ArcGIS for Desktop (just after the example with QGIS).

---

If you have access to QGIS (or ArcGIS Pro), I support @user30184’s suggestion to convert the GeoJSON into another file format and read the intermediate file with ArcGIS Desktop.